# jQuery command works in browser's console but not in code

Tags: jquery

I have this code within the `body` tag.

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function (){
        console.log("ok")
        $("a:contains('Přidat Agr Mapa')").css("display", "none")
    })
</script>
```

when the page is loaded, ok is printed into the console. The link is not hidden.
if I run
`$("a:contains('Přidat Agr Mapa')").css("display", "none")`
in the console, the link is hidden.

Why is it not working from the script?

Edit: HTML

```
{% load i18n admin_urls static admin_modify %}
<div class="js-inline-admin-formset inline-group" id="{{ inline_admin_formset.formset.prefix }}-group"
     data-inline-type="tabular"
     data-inline-formset="{{ inline_admin_formset.inline_formset_data }}">
    <div class="tabular inline-related {% if forloop.last %}last-related{% endif %}">
        {{ inline_admin_formset.formset.management_form }}
        <fieldset class="module {{ inline_admin_formset.classes }}">
        <h2>{{ inline_admin_formset.opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}</h2>
        {{ inline_admin_formset.formset.non_form_errors }}
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="original"></th>
                    {% for field in inline_admin_formset.fields %}
                        {% if not field.widget.is_hidden %}
                            <th {% if field.required %}class="required"{% endif %} scope="col">{{ field.label|capfirst }}
                                {% if field.help_text %}&nbsp;<img src="{% static "admin/img/icon-unknown.svg" %}" class="help help-tooltip" width="10" height="10" alt="({{ field.help_text|striptags }})" title="{{ field.help_text|striptags }}">{% endif %}
                            </th>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% if inline_admin_formset.formset.can_delete %}<th>{% trans "Delete?" %}</th>{% endif %}
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            {% for inline_admin_form in inline_admin_formset %}
                {% if inline_admin_form.form.non_field_errors %}
                    <tr><td colspan="{{ inline_admin_form|cell_count }}">{{ inline_admin_form.form.non_field_errors }}</td></tr>
                {% endif %}
                <tr class="{% if inline_admin_form.original or inline_admin_form.show_url %}has_original{% endif %}{% if forloop.last and inline_admin_formset.has_add_permission %} empty-form{% endif %}"
                    id="{{ inline_admin_formset.formset.prefix }}-{% if not forloop.last %}{{ forloop.counter0 }}{% else %}empty{% endif %}">
                <td class="original">
                {% if inline_admin_form.original or inline_admin_form.show_url %}
                    <p>
                        {% if inline_admin_form.original %}
                            {{ inline_admin_form.original }}
                            {% if inline_admin_form.model_admin.show_change_link and inline_admin_form.model_admin.has_registered_model %}<a href="{% url inline_admin_form.model_admin.opts|admin_urlname:'change' inline_admin_form.original.pk|admin_urlquote %}" class="{% if inline_admin_formset.has_change_permission %}inlinechangelink{% else %}inlineviewlink{% endif %}">{% if inline_admin_formset.has_change_permission %}{% trans "Change" %}{% else %}{% trans "View" %}{% endif %}</a>{% endif %}
                        {% endif %}
                        {% if inline_admin_form.show_url %}<a href="{{ inline_admin_form.absolute_url }}">{% trans "View on site" %}</a>{% endif %}
                    </p>
                {% endif %}
                {% if inline_admin_form.needs_explicit_pk_field %}{{ inline_admin_form.pk_field.field }}{% endif %}
                {{ inline_admin_form.fk_field.field }}
                {% spaceless %}
                    {% for fieldset in inline_admin_form %}
                        {% for line in fieldset %}
                            {% for field in line %}
                                {% if field.field.is_hidden %} {{ field.field }} {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endspaceless %}
                </td>
                {% for fieldset in inline_admin_form %}
                    {% for line in fieldset %}
                        {% for field in line %}
                        {% if not field.field.is_hidden %}
                            <td {% if field.field.name %}class="field-{{ field.field.name }}"{% endif %}>
                        {% if field.is_readonly %}
                            <p>{{ field.contents }}</p>
                        {% else %}
                            {{ field.field.errors.as_ul }}
                            {{ field.field }}
                        {% endif %}
                        </td>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% if inline_admin_formset.formset.can_delete %}
                    <td class="delete">{% if inline_admin_form.original %}{{ inline_admin_form.deletion_field.field }}{% endif %}</td>
                {% endif %}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function (){
        console.log("ok")
        $("a:contains('Přidat Agr Mapa')").css("display", "none")
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Most likely cause could be your selector - what does the html look like?

Comment: added, its a django page, but I always use scripts like these for little changes but this time it is different

Comment: Try $(window).load and check if it works

Comment: Also, you could try `console.log($("a:contains('Přidat Agr Mapa')"))` to see if JQuery actually manages to select it.

Comment: `$(window).load`  did the trick, thank you! respectively `$(window).on('load',function (){ ..`